# WebView Android - Proper way to queue asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, android, asynchronous, webview, promise

I've got an Android app that I'm implementing in a webview. A fundamental piece of my app is that I have a queue for retrying certain API calls (queue exists because they need to happen in order, but network conditions are not always reliable, so I have to retry when it fails).

The following code shows the basics of what I do: I call the API, if it succeeds I remove the job and go onto the next job in the queue; otherwise I log the error, wait 5 seconds, and then try to process it again.

```
return callAPI(job.parameters).then(function(result){
    _queue._removeJob(job.id);
    processNext();
}).catch(function(e){
    // need to be able to tell the difference between a NETWORK error and an API error
    // retry later on NETWORK error
    // record all other errors, along with the parameters
     Logger.log('API error', e);
     setTimeout(processNext,5000)
})
```

My queue system works alright 99% of the time, but sometimes for some reason the promise never ends in .then or .catch, so 'processNext' never gets called.

I'm cool with maybe using a Promise.race() to set a timeout condition where it errors and goes into .catch, but I'm worried about what happens on phones where the app isn't in focus -- what happens to this queue when the app is in the background? Is there a more appropriate way to run this queue? Should I set some external `setInterval` to periodically check that the queue is running as intended, and start it up again if it hasn't gone in say 2 minutes?

Comment: `the promise never ends in .then or .catch` - that would be a logic issue in `callAPI`

Comment: @JaromandaX good point. However I can confirm that the promise will end in .then or .catch with  the same reliability as '$.ajax' ends in its success / error callbacks, because `callAPI` is just a wrapper for an ajax call and always resolves or rejects in those callbacks.

Comment: then there's absolutely no reason to think that neither .then nor .catch are called - you're using native promises? not some broken implementation of promises?

Comment: Native, yes, but it's inside of a webview of an android app and I don't know how the app not having focus would affect things.